# AngularJS routing with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I begin to use AngularJS with my Rails application but when i tried to implement my route providers with Angular, it's not working and Rails view is displayed instead of my template.

**routes.rb** :

```
root 'tutorials#index'
```

**TutorialsController** :

```
    def index
    @tutorials = Tutorial.all

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render :json => @tutorials }
    end
end
```

app/views/tutorials/index.html.erb :

```
<html ng-app="Tutorial">
<body>
    <div class="container" ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
```

assets/javascripts/tutorials.js :

```
var Tutorial = angular.module('Tutorial', ['ngRoute']);
```

Tutorial.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

$log.debug( "Configuring $routeProvider...");

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider.
when('/tutorials', {
    templateUrl: '../templates/tutorials/index.html',
    controller: 'TutorialController'
}).
otherwise({
    templateUrl: '../templates/tutorials/index.html',
    controller: 'TutorialController'
});
```

});

and assets/templates/tutorials/index.html just displayed tutorials' title with a controller not shown in tutorials.js because it's not relevant here.

So instead having my angular route provider redirect me to index.html, i have a blank page representing my index.html.erb.

Any idea ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is largely caused by Turbolinks.

You should remove the following line from your app/assets/javascripts/application.js file:

```
//= require turbolinks
```

if you already removed the turbolinks, change this line something like this:

from

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

to

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```